# Making a Shopify app public

Tags: shopify

I'm commissioning a developer to build a shopify app in ruby, and it will be private as just used for a clients project. However if I choose to use the bulk of this for a public app at some point is there any major technical headache in taking an app that was initially made private to be public, or is it just a case of changing a few settings? I'm just trying to plan this right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be trivial to make it public. I do that all the time, and it takes mere seconds to swap a pair of API keys and the URL. So you are good to go there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I've since read that the oauth is fiddly and it's much easier to do at the start - is that true or again or there little difference?

Comment: OAuth is not fiddly. It is pretty much the standard you'll find in use at most API driven properties. Since your private App uses it, your public App uses it. No difference, hence I can say it again, it is trivial to move from private to public use with an App.